# SDK version rendering problems

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I was updated my android studio SDK version `API level 23` to `26`. Now my older project fetching problems. How can I resolve this problem?

> Error is: Failed to load the LayoutLib:
>   com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version
>   52.0 (Details)

and my build.gradle error is:

[build.gradle screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPjCb.png)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0izj.png)

Comment: I think is because you `compileSdkVersion` is less than the `targetSdkVersion` he need to be the same.

Comment: your minSdkVersion 26 and compileSdkVersion is 23, You just think how it will work ?

Comment: Change `targetSdkVersion` to `23` or change `compileSdkVersion` to `26` and remove `buildToolsVerison` or change it to `26.X.X`

Comment: oh sorry... i wasn't seen it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follow

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 26.1.0
Install Build Tools 26.1.0 and sync project

Comment: Then install them